# Syntax Error In Postgresql Function

Tags: postgresql, functions, syntax

Why am I getting:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'SELECT '"
```

In:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetListings (lon double precision, lat double precision, schemas name[]) 
RETURNS TABLE(
  schema VARCHAR(128),
  id BIGINT,
  product_name VARCHAR(128),
  product_type SMALLINT,
  product_subtype SMALLINT,
  product_units SMALLINT,
  product_info JSONB,
  product_image VARCHAR(256),
  is_featured BOOLEAN,
  is_special BOOLEAN,
  is_alert BOOLEAN,
  distributor_name VARCHAR(128),
  distributor_image VARCHAR(256)
) AS $$
DECLARE
  sch name;
  n text;
  t text;
BEGIN

  n := to_char(lon,'999.999999999999999');
  t := to_char(lat,'999.999999999999999');

  FOREACH sch IN ARRAY schemas 
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY 'SELECT ''' || sch || ''', product_name, product_type, product_subtype, product_units, product_info, product_image, is_featured, is_special, is_alert, distributor_name, distributor_image FROM ' || quote_ident(sch) || '.listing WHERE ST_Contains(area, ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(' || n || ', ' || t || '), 4326))';
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` for dynamic SQL.

With `RETURN QUERY` you're trying to use a string literal as the start of a query. That's nonsensical and raises a syntax error.

Also, use `format` with the `%I` and `%L` specifiers for identifiers and literals, instead of using concatenation. Otherwise you have SQL injection issues in your function.